# Compile simple UDP server using clang got error: use of undeclared identifier 'SA'

Tags: c, sockets, clang

I was trying to make the simple server code work:

```
/*
NAME:        udpServer0 
SYNOPSIS:    udpServer0 
DESCRIPTION:    The program creates a datagram socket in the inet 
                domain, binds it to port 12345 and receives any message
                arrived to the socket and prints it out
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void)
{
   int   sd;
   struct   sockaddr_in server;
   char buf[512];
   int rc;

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   server.sin_port = htons(12345);

   sd = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    bind( sd, (SA *) &server, sizeof(server));

   for(;;){
      rc=recv (sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
      buf[rc]= (char) NULL;
      printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
   }
}
```

I got these error:

```
clang udp_server.c                
udp_server.c:27:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SA'
    bind( sd, (SA *) &server, sizeof(server));
               ^
udp_server.c:27:20: error: expected expression
    bind( sd, (SA *) &server, sizeof(server));
                   ^
2 errors generated.
```

Do I need to require some header to avoid this problem?

Comment: Try `struct sockaddr` instead of SA. The latter doesn't necessarily exist in any system header.

Comment: @n.m. I'm new to socket programming, could you provide more details about it?

Comment: `bind` needs a parameter of type `struct sockaddr *`. SA is probably an alias of this type that is defined somewhere in the program you have used as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say you want: (struct sockaddr *) instead of (SA *).

SA must have been a typedef. If you want the best guide to socket programming see this: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html